# POSTing multiple parameters to endpoint in python

Tags: python, post, request

Using request lib, I want to post more than 1 parameter to a URL/endpoint.

```
data1="lol"
data2="lol2"

payload = {'data1param': data1}
r = requests.get('https://example.com/endpoint.php', params=payload)
```

How do I post more than 1 parameter?

Do I modify payload like

```
  payload = {'data1param': data1, 'data2param': data2)
```

Just need to confirm my syntax because I am getting null when POST-ing more than 1 parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want send data in request body, use this approach:

```
payload = {'data1param': data1, 'data2param': data2}
r = requests.post('https://example.com/endpoint.php', data=payload)
```

If in query params:

```
payload = {'data1param': data1, 'data2param': data2}
r = requests.post('https://example.com/endpoint.php', params=payload)
# It's equal to https://example.com/endpoint.php?data1param=...&data2param=...
```